# Locked/Unlocked in title

Tags: posts, password

This should be incredibly easy, but I'm missing something.  This code should simply work if they have entered their password into a password protected post/page. The idea is to remind them it is protected.

However... I can't get it to work at all.  The if statement never returns true.  For some reason, I don't think the function is getting $post.

```
function unlocked() {
  if(!empty($post->post_password) && !post_password_required()) {
    echo 'unlocked icon reminding them this was protected and they put in their password already';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function will never "get" `$post` as this is not how functions work. Functions cannot pull anything into itself by itself. If you have debug turned on, you will get a definite bug notice that `$post` in undefined.....

You would need to invoke the `$post` global inside your function for anything to work that relies on the `$post` global, so the following would work

```
function unlocked() {
  global $post;

  if(!empty($post->post_password) && !post_password_required()) {
    echo 'unlocked icon reminding them this was protected and they put in their password already';
  }
}
```

Comment: Holy heck!  Thank you very much. I should have realized that.  Especially considering the amount of time I put into researching an answer.